# CTFontCopyFamilyName() causes leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, core-text

I am developing a program, that uses Core Text... And I have a leak in the following line of code:

```
NSString *familyName = (NSString*)CTFontCopyFamilyName(font);
```

When I write `CFRelease((CFStringRef)familyName);` I get bad access exception. When I write `[familyName release];` I have the same issue. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
NSString *familyName = [(NSString*)CTFontCopyFamilyName(font) autorelease];
```

Comment: Same as my answer, but You are first so I'm deleting mine. 17 sec :)

Comment: @JustinBoo - at same time we saw same question. :)